# cx_Oracle Python Connectivity with Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

when trying to use 'cx_Oracle' library in python, I am getting the following error:
'No module named custom_exceptions'.

I am using python 3.7 with Oracle 11.2

Comment: `custom_exceptions` does not appear to be a standard Python module, nor one that `cx_Oracle` depends on.  `cx_Oracle` works fine for me and I have no `custom_exceptions` module.  You haven't included your code, nor the full traceback; without these I can only guess that `custom_exceptions` is one of your own modules and the problem isn't anything to do with `cx_Oracle`.  However, I am willing to be proved wrong on this if you edit your question and include your code and traceback.

Comment: The issue was that I was using Anaconda 64 bit with Oracle 32 bits, when I used both 64 bits. This error is no longer happening